# SATA to USB adapter disconnects, reconnects, disconnects, reconnects, etc. when plugged in... how do I fix it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive

I've got a [Weme SATA/PATA to USB adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MVRS38Q) and it works fine on every computer (tried 3 or 4) except my laptop. On my laptop it just connects, disconnects (USB bing-bong, bing-bong) ad infinitum. I actually have two identical adapters, and both behave the same way in this computer. Also tried various drives and they all behave the same way. Also, I recently (two days ago) migrated to a new laptop using the same disk image, and discovered the problem was there on the original -- so it's happening on two different laptops which run the same Windows install. I've plugged in external USB devices (MyBook and Passport) and those work fine. I even plugged a PATA drive into this same adapter and that also works on my laptop (I noticed in device manager different drivers get loaded depending on what drive you connect through the same adapter). All of the above seems to narrow it down, the adapter hardware didn't become defective, it's not the hard drive, it's not the laptop's hardware, which seems to pretty much leave something about the Windows 10 install.  But what?

I looked at the filter drivers, didn't see anything amiss there. I re-installed any third-party software I could think of that might get triggered by a USB disk being added. I did the trick where you uninstall each USB device / hub / root device / etc. listed in device manager, and nothing resolved the issue.  I did sfc /verifyonly and no problems.  And I just upgraded to 20H2 hoping that a major update might fix it.  No change.

I looked through the Windows event logs and the only entries that relate seem to be in the System log, which has Unexpected failure. Error code: 1B1@01010013 from the VDS Basic Provider and C000000E020A0007 from Virtual Disk Service, but find little about those errors, and they could just be errors in response to the sudden disconnects rather than the cause of the disconnects.

Anyone have any other ideas? Everything otherwise with this laptop works fine. I'm out of ideas of things to try. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Boot a Linux Live environment from USB.  If the problem persists, then its a hardware issue with those drives and the laptop.  If it does work, you might want to grab a spare drive and install Windows on it on that laptop.  If the problem stops occurring, then its something with the original install.

Personally, I wouldnt spend much more time than this.  Sometimes its just easier, less time consuming, and less frustrating to simply replace the hardware.  Just buy another SATA/PATA to USB adapter.  You can get these for just a few dollars on eBay or Amazon.

Comment: Thanks.  I did that, that's how I cloned the original image to the new laptop.  Under Linux (clonezilla live boot) all worked perfectly.  There's just something weird about this Windows install working with this adapter.  My fear is just that since this SATA to USB adapter doesn't require any drivers, and is pretty generic, any other generic adapters I get may have the same issue.  But, point taken.  It's driving me a bit mad, so I'll need to give up one way or the other.